# Windows Azure Service Mobile get All data from table

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

I need a little bit of help with Windows Azure and the query system.

I can get data from the first row with this query

```
Table.where().field("id").eq("1").execute().get();
```

but I want to get all of my table data (about 50 rows).

Is there a query to get all the rows at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the `where` call and call `execute` on the table directly:

```
Table.execute().get();
```

Comment: This still only return 50 rows.